# Getting the filenames of all open documents in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, windows-10, windows-scripting

I am trying to write a script that saves all the open the programs, documents, files and webpages as a workspace. Ideally, I would like to use the script to save the workspace and then for it to reopen once I click another script (ie. the saved workspace). I have several jobs that I am doing concurrently and I would like to be able to shuffle between these jobs with just a click. I am aware of multiple desktops and such but I wanted something different that saves me from constantly having to open all the files and pages each time I intend to work on a particular task. Also, I did not want to be installing any additional software and I just wanted it to operate from a script, if possible.

For the coding, I went with VBScript. I am able to open the files, but I can't figure out how to check which files are open and their filepaths. This is part of the code I have so far:

```
Set Word = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
Word. --- I'm trying to get documents to work here and to get
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I've now changed your tags, to reflect your Operating System, and replaced the vbscript one to windows-scripting, to allow for more scripting options than just that. You have still not explained why you included autohotkey, and if there are any other software products you have available, which could be used as part of the solution.

Comment: \I just added AHK in case it was possible to do it with that program. By additional software, I meant applications such as DisplayFusion.

Comment: So potentially, responders could ask you to download standalone utilities, or even install software, should they wish to, is that correct? _I'm not even sure how DisplayFusion would be relevant, as I thought it was a hotkey programmable utility for customising monitors/desktops_.

Comment: Yes that would be fine. I wanted to try it with a script first if it is possible.

Comment: I thought DisplayFusion was something along the lines of what I was looking. I brought it up because that was one of the programs that was suggested on forums. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve quite what I was looking for. I wanted something where I could essentially save the virtual workspaces so I can return to them at a later point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the current open documents:

```vb
' Note: Leaving the first parameter, the pathname, empty as it's not
'       required, and passing an empty string will cause an isolated 
'       instance of Word to be loaded
Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
For Each doc In Word.Documents
    WScript.Echo "Name: " + doc.Name + ", Full name: """ + doc.FullName + """"
Next
```

This outputs the following for me, obviously your list will differ depending on what's open:

```
Name: Document1, Full name: "Document1"
Name: Example Doc.docx, Full name: "C:\Files\Example Doc.docx"
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. That was exactly it and it works for me. Also, thank you about the first parameter. I was having an issue with that as well